# Bounded idempotent on Hilbert space has closed range.

Tags: functional-analysis, projection

Let $H$ be a Hilbert space and $p\in B(H)$ an idempotent on $H$, i.e. a continuous linear map satisfying $p^2 = p$. Is it true that $p(H)$ is a closed subspace of $H$?

**Attempt**:

Consider a sequence $p(h_n) \to h $. We show $h \in p(H)$. By continuity, $$p(h_n) = p^2(h_n) = p(p(h_n)) \to p(h)$$ but also $p(h_n) \to h$ so we obtain $h = p(h) \in p(H)$ and we are done.

Is this correct?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, your proof is correct.

As an alternative approach, we could note that $p(H) = \ker(\operatorname{id}_H - p)$, and the kernel of any bounded linear map is closed.

Comment: Nice alternative solution. Thanks for sharing!